# vb.net send a login and password to the process

Tags: vb.net

From my code at vb.net, I run a process with several arguments. the process starts and stops waiting for entering the login and pressing the enter button, then waits for the password to be entered and the button to be pressed. Then the process starts. Unfortunately, the process does not have any arguments username/password. I do not know how to implement entering the username, password in the process.

```
Dim proc As New Process()
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "e:\myapp\app.exe"
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "arg1" & "arg2" & "arg3"
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
```

Comment: So you start a third party process? Do you have access to the source of the application that you want to start?

Comment: unfortunately I do not have access to the source code. application that I run the exe file

Comment: Is the other app a commandline app or a GUI? You talk about buttons so I'm guessing GUI.  If the app provides no API then you would have no option but to use the Windows API, i.e. `FindWindow`, `FindWindowEx` and `SendMessage`.

Comment: I apologize for the bad description, the application commandline and api is missing.